# Seatpost clamp arrow and too wide saddle rails

Tags: saddle, seatpost, clamp, rails

I have two questions in one: :)
The first would be what direction does [this arrow on the seatpost's top clamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL56i.jpg) indicate? Is it towards the front or rear of the bike?

Second would be what should I do if [my saddle rails are too far apart to fit the clamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bao0.jpg)?

Comment: the arrow points forward & i'm not convinced by that photo that clamp is too narrow.

Comment: Does the top clamp fit over the rails?

Comment: Looks like you can just bend the saddle rails to fit

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. I actually just screwed the clamps in and it seems to work pretty well.

None of them (top and bottom seemed to fit.